# memory error for finding anagrams of a word in a given word

Tags: python-3.x

I am writing a code to find anagram of a word in a given word,my code is working in offline compilers but not running in online editor , i am getting memory error for it .Below is my code:

Help me to solve this error

```
import itertools
s=input()
c=input()
sum=0
a=list("".join(perm) for perm in itertools.permutations(c) )
print(a)
for i in a:
    cnt=s.count(i)
    sum=sum+cnt

print(sum)
```

this is my output:-
Runtime Error:
MemoryError

Comment: how big is `c`? Why are you creating a giant list out of it, instead of using the iterator that is returned?

Comment: Most likely `c` is just too big.  If `c` is n digits long then there are n! possible permutations.  If `c` is length 10 (for example) then that is 3628800 possible permutations.